# Antiquated Notation with number preceded by L

Tags: notation

I am reading Fourier's "Analytical Theory of Heat" and I am not certain what the meaning of a number preceded by an L (as if it were a bracket).  I am guessing that it is the factorial operation - from the context in the picture below, the equation appears to be a Taylor series.

Does anyone know for a certainty what it means?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old way of writing [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).  See [A History of Mathematical Notation](https://archive.org/details/AHistoryOfMathematicalNotationVolII/page/n93/mode/2up)

${\displaystyle \vert \!{\underline {\,n}}} = \prod\limits_{k=1}^n k$